# Java: Checking the type of the receiver of an Executable element

Tags: java, string, reflection, metaprogramming

Let's say I have a method which takes an `ExecutableElement` as an argument. I know I can use `ExecutableElement.getReceiverType` to extract it's type. Now I want to check if the receiver type of this method is a `String`. ie this method belongs to the `String` class. How can I do that?

Comment: `Now I want to check if the receiver type of this method` do you mean type of parameters?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn No, the type of the class to which this method belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Use utility class `Types` and `Elements`.

```
javax.lang.model.util.Types types; // this two util objects are from your context.
javax.lang.model.util.Elements elements;
TypeMirror stringType = elements.getTypeElement(String.class.getCanonicalName()).asType(); // get string type
types.isSameType(executableElement.getReceiverType(), stringType);
```

or you can simply compare its name

```
executableElement.getReceiverType().toString().equals(String.class.getCanonicalName())
```

Answer (score -1):

You use `instanceof` operator to check if a class is a certain type:

```
if (ExecutableElement.getReceiverType() instanceof String) {
     ....
}
```